# Wordpress Post limit?

Tags: wordpress, post, limit

I want adapt the following code for WordPress, please help me.

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE cat='1' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5,10");

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to select?  You can use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to get a group of posts, or you can use the [`WP_Query` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if you need something more involved.

Assuming you want posts, then, to duplicate your SQL query:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',  // default
    'order'          => 'DESC',       // default
    'offset'         => 5,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category'       => 1,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: The OP may also need the `paged` parameter (`paged => get_query_var('page')`), if they wish to implement pagination. If that is the case, I agree that they really should look at `WP_Query` as you suggested.